# Android: get position within ListView on Long Click

Tags: android, listview

So, I know that there are plenty of similar questions on Stack; however, none of them managed to solve my issue.

I have a `ListActivity` activity for displaying a list of usernames; 
I created a `UserObj` class to collect information about each user, i.e.,  `UserObj` instance (username, password, etc..).

Now I am showing successfully the username within my `ListView` and I also managed to show a floating `ContextMenu` with some items (`Delete`,`ChangeUsername`,`ChangePassword`,`ChangeEmail`) upon long-clicking on a particular username. 
Below I post my `ListActivity` code:

```
public class ShowAccountList extends ListActivity {
 List<UserObj> Allusers = new ArrayList<>(); // this is required to retrieve users from a local database

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_account_list);

    final ListView UserList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    UserList.setLongClickable(true);

  /*For completeness: here I fetch users from DB*/
    DataBaseUserHelper dbusers  = new DataBaseUserHelper(getApplicationContext());
    dbusers.CreateTables();
     Allusers = dbusers.getAllUsers();
     dbusers.closeDB();

   /*Let's build a 'username' list to display*/
    List<String> namelist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0 ; i< Allusers.size() ; i++){
        String uname = Allusers.get(i).username;
        namelist.add(uname);
    }

    final ArrayAdapter<String> nameadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,namelist);
    UserList.setAdapter(nameadapter);

   registerForContextMenu(UserList);

    UserList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            openContextMenu(parent);

            /*This outputs the CORRECT position*/
            System.out.println("Position: " + position + ", id: " + id); 
            return true;
        }



    });



}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.user_context_menu, menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    int selectedId = info.position;  // HERE the problem shows up

     // switch statement for debugging purposes 
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.DeleteUser:

            System.out.println("DELETE USER");
            return true;
        case R.id.ChangeName:
            System.out.println("CHANGE USERNAME");
            return true;
        case R.id.ChangeEmail:
            System.out.println("CHANGE EMAIL");
            return true;
        case R.id.ChangePassword:
            System.out.println("CHANGE PASSWORD");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

    }
}
}
```

However, what I need to do, obviously, is to actually trigger the execution of the 'delete user', 'change email', etc... tasks for the selected user; what I supposed was that the `position` of the corresponding **list item** would be required in order to know **which** user should have undergone these modifications. 
So, following the suggestions of the majority of the questions (and of the corresponding answers) on this topic, I casted `item.getMenuInfo()` to  `AdapterContextMenuInfo` within `onContextItemSelected` and then I tried to retrieve the position with:

```
  int selectedId = info.position;
```

The problem is that when I select one menu item (e.g., the one corresponding to 'delete') the ANR dialog shows up and the following exception is reported:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterContextMenuInfo.position' on a null object reference
```

What I can understand is that `info.position` is always null. But why?
What could be the problem in my code?

As you can see from the code above, I tried to see what happened when clicking each single menu item by printing a test string (e.g., `"DELETE USER"`) and actually if I remove `int selectedId = info.position;` no crash occurs...

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

After some diagnosis, I figured out that the `menuInfo` passed to `onCreateContextMenu` is NULL. So, I got a little bit closer to the origin of the problem. 
Any idea why I am getting a NULL `menuInfo`?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem. My solution was to register view for context menu inside the adapter using `activity.registerForContextMenu(view)`

The position of the item or even  UserObj can be set as tag in the view.

You can get the tag in the `onCreateContextMenu()` call and corresponding action could be invoked.

Comment: Ok, I had already tried to register view in this way but it did not work... Anyway thank you very much for the 'setTag()' suggestion :) I will try it hoping to circumvent the previous issue

Comment: I would like also to ask this... Is there a way to perform the desired action in `onContextItemSelected` instead of `onCreateContextMenu`? Because what I need is to restrict my attention on one user and then choose an action for that user. And the chosen action will be available in `onContextItemSelected`, isn't it?

Comment: @rabis I just edited my question. I realized I am passing a NULL `menuInfo` to `onCreateContextMenu`.

Comment: Ok, both answers helped me a little bit and that's why I upvoted, but my problem was completely different...   I eventually figured out that my mistake was returning **true** within **onItemLongClick**.  Setting it to return **false** was enough to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the best way, you should create custom adapter, then implement custom listener in activity when event occur (onClick, onLongClick...)
2. About your problem, I think you was wrong when implement @rabhis idea. 
   Try my solution that I have implemented in my app: 
   (In my code, I used custom adapter with recycleview, so try to merge to your code)

   - Class implement:

> `public class ListHistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListHistoryAdapter.HistoryViewHolder> implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {`

- In **public void onBindViewHolder** method:

> `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>                   @Override
>                   public void onClick(View v) {
>                       // your code
>                   }
>               });
>   holder.itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
>   holder.itemView.setTag(position);`

- Override in adapter:

> `@Override
>       public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
>           MenuItem deleteItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Delete");
>           final int pos = (int) v.getTag();
>           deleteItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
>               @Override
>               public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
>                   // your code
>                   return true;
>               }
>           });
>       }`

Comment: Ok, both answers helped me a little bit and that's why I upvoted, but my problem was completely different...   I eventually figured out that my mistake was returning **true** within **onItemLongClick**.  Setting it to return **false** was enough to solve the issue.